PgAdmin4 unable to query or view data generated in a table by prisma
I am making use of prisma ORM to connect to my database and create table to read or write data to the table using postgres server. I was able to follow the prisma get started tutorial prisma-get-started and and successfully created 3 tables, when I use prisma-client to read data from the tables in my code it successfully return data for me.
My schema
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://jideotetic:Jideotetic012345$@localhost:5432/mini_message_board?schema=public"
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  content   String?
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  author    User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}

model Profile {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  bio    String?
  user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int     @unique
}

model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email   String   @unique
  name    String?
  posts   Post[]
  profile Profile?
}

My index.ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
    const allUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({
        include: {
            posts: true,
            profile: true,
        },
    });
    console.dir(allUsers, { depth: null });
}

main()
    .then(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    })
    .catch(async (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        await prisma.$disconnect();
        process.exit(1);
    });

The response
[
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'alice@prisma.io',
    name: 'Alice',
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        createdAt: 2024-10-27T19:06:37.382Z,
        updatedAt: 2024-10-27T19:20:26.176Z,
        title: 'Hello World',
        id: 1,
        createdAt: 2024-10-27T19:06:37.382Z,
        updatedAt: 2024-10-27T19:20:26.176Z,
        title: 'Hello World',
        title: 'Hello World',
        content: null,
        published: true,
        authorId: 1
      }
    profile: { id: 1, bio: 'I like turtles', userId: 1 }
  }
]

The issue I am having is that when I open my PgAdmin4 for postgres and connect to my database, I can see those 3 tables in my schema view but when I use a select statement to query data from the table it keeps returning an error that the table cannot be found

Other tables I created using the GUI are working fine, I need assistance on how I can get this working...I can provide further clarifications if needed.

The table's name is Post, not post. Try SELECT * FROM "Post". Names that include uppercase characters require quoting with ".
